# Symfony2 DATEDIFF function

Tags: php, symfony, twig, datediff

I need to fill table in TWIG with data from database. Everything is Fine with the exception of this:

I need to have column with DATEDIFF property to get number of days.

> TODAY-dateFromDateBase

Question is:
*How to get number of days in loop in twig?*

**here is my twig:**

```
<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(searchform) }} class="form-index-permits">
                    <td>L.p </td>
                    <td>ID PRZEPUSTKI {{ form_widget(searchform.PermitId) }}</td>
                    <td>Name{{ form_widget(searchform.Permitname) }}</td>
                    <td>Surname {{ form_widget(searchform.Permitsurname) }}</td>
                    <td>Company {{ form_widget(searchform.Company) }}</td>
                    <td>GW {{ form_widget(searchform.Contractor) }}</td>
                    <td>Dayleft {{ form_widget(searchform.Dayleft) }}</td>
                    <td>End date {{ form_widget(searchform.date, { 'attr': {'class': 'datepicker'} }) }}</td>

                </form>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            {% for permit in permitcollection %}
                <tbody>
                <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
                <td>{{ permit.getPermitid()|number_format(0, '.', ' ') }}</td>
                <td>{{ permit.getPermitname() }}</td>
                <td>{{ permit.getPermitsurname() }}</td>
                <td>{{ permit.getPermitsCompany().getName() }}</td>
                <td>{{ permit.getPermitsContractor().getName() }}</td>
                <td> HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY DAYS LEFT</td>
                <td>{{ permit.getExpirationdate()|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>

                </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Is something like this possible?

```
{{ permit.getExpirationdate()|date('Y-m-d') - "now"|date('Y-m-d')  }}
```

Comment: I find very useful the [Carbon PHP library](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon). I suggest you to take a look at [this part of the doc](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#difference-for-humans) and expose this as a twig extension. Hope this help

Comment: cant you calculate in controller and add to you viewmodel ?

Answer (score 4):

**First Solution (recommended)  "Use an existing library":**

You can use the [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle)

In the Twig:
This compare with the current date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(permit.expirationDate) }}
```

This compare with the another date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(permit.expirationDate, anotherDate) }}
```

**Second Solution  "Do it yourself":**

Make diff via php function:

```
$calcFrom = permit.getExpirationdate()

$now = new \DateTime('now');
$now->diff($calcFrom)->format("%a")
```

And make it available via a [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) or directly in an helper method in the entity.

**Another possible solution** is to write register a [custom DQL Function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) to do the work in the repository

Hope this help

Comment: is something like this possible?{{ permit.getExpirationdate()|date('Y-m-d') - "now"|date('Y-m-d')  }}

Comment: any other way without New Bundle?;/\

Comment: If you want to implement yourself, check the source code of the knp-time-bundle. I suggest you to use the bundle, is well written, tested and maintained from top developer of the symfony framework itself.